# Guardar imagen localmente en un registro

Tags: html, angular, typescript, phpmyadmin, local-storage

estoy intentando guardar imágenes de un registro x en  equipo, pero quisiera que se me guarden en assent en una carpeta en especifica , pero no se implementar el método.
se que utilizo un div con una clase file upload y en el input un change:event y lo llamo desde el .ts , el detalle es que no se como llevarlo a cabo.

[image: y este es el código que tengo en el equipocomponent.ts(claro esta el método no tiene nada declarado)]

[image: este es el código que tengo en equipocomponent.html]

[image: este es el formulario de registro]

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar más detalles?  No se entiende lo que pretendes.  De paso el código va como texto no en imágenes.

Comment: mira te explico; tengo un component de registro de quipo , ya ese component me funciona perfectamente con base de dato , ya registro todo perfecto , el detalle es que quisiera que el quipo pueda subir una x imagen que pertenezcan a ello , pero no se como implementar el servicio de almacenar una imagen localmente en una carpeta atravez de un input.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.